# MILP - How to set variable to be absolute value of other variable

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

In a Milp, given an integer variable x, I would like to define a variable y which will be the absolute value of x.

y = |x|

x is bounded between [M, -M].

Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not exactly what I asked for, but it does solve my problem :)

Comment: In general `y=|x|` needs a binary variable unless we know something special about the objective. The referenced answer is wrong (in general we can't use a penalty, as this changes the model).

Comment: Yes, I assumed it could be done using a binary variable and "big M", but I wasn't successful in finding the right formulation, or looking it up online.

For my problem, the penalty woud have been to minimize these absolute values so the provided answer did help me

Comment: Using AMPL's piecewise-linear notation to express the absolute value function explicitly as a piecewise-linear function with slope -1 to the left of 0 (breakpoint) and +1 to the right of 0.
below AMPL snippet achieves the following `y = abs(x)`

`ampl: var x <= -10, >= -50;`
`ampl: var y >= 0;`
`ampl: subject to absConstr: y = <<0;-1,+1>> x;`
`ampl: maximize y_variable: y;`
`ampl: options solver highs;`
`ampl: solve;`

Post the successful solve:

`x = -50` (considering the bounds), and `y =   50`